# OpenLayers 3: "Unable to get property 'leaf' of undefined or null reference."

Tags: addition, layer, openlayers-3

Using Open layers 3.7.0.
I have layer with features. I remove one, build a new similar one, add the new one  and I get error message
"Unable to get property 'leaf' of undefined or null reference."

I have searched for what could cause that but search don't give any result.

Some more from the same error (I used v3.8.2 here but got exactly the same:
   at rbush.prototype._chooseSubtree (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/build/ol-debug.js:70778:13)
   at rbush.prototype._insert (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/build/ol-debug.js:70815:9)

at rbush.prototype.insert (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/build/ol-debug.js:70623:19)
at ol.structs.RBush.prototype.insert (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/build/ol-debug.js:71178:3)
at ol.source.Vector.prototype.addFeatureInternal (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/build/ol-debug.js:71589:7)
at ol.source.Vector.prototype.addFeature (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/build/ol-debug.js:71566:3)

**Progress**

Where we build the feature we have a projection.

```
var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
lineString.transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");
var feature = new ol.Feature(lineString);
(...)
```

If we comment/remove

```
//lineString.transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");
```

Then there is no bug. By the way that's an hint, not a solution as the features are then not located where they should be.

**Solution found**

I do not think that this is a perfect soluton but I solved the problem regarding or application by saving the LineStrings in memory instead of re-creating it.
Then I still recreate the Feature from existing LineString.

Comment: This might be a bug. Can you share the code that you use to create a feature, delete it, and add a similar one?

Comment: Sorry it's quite complex to extract the code from the application so it is not done for now, but I edited the original post with some progress.

Comment: I found a solution regarding our application, which doesn't clearly identify or solve the bug. (See original post.)

Comment: One of my colleagues found: apparently the problem was that I was using projection for coordinates and when I was recreating the object I was re-projecting already projected coordinates, which resulted in very big numbers. So that was mostly  a bug in my code, note in the library.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on console and I solved this testing if the features had a valid geometry(coordinates), so I discard the inclusion of the invalid features on the layer source.